# Lock content in WordPress website

Tags: plugins

I have a big WordPress site, there is a thousands posts, now I want to lock just all **links** in the whole posts and make it available to members only, I know that is a many plugins make private content, but it so hard to paste the their short codes on all posts one by one!

Comment: what do you mean lock a link in a post for members only?

Comment: I mean that only website members can view the links inside posts